# Can server host see what my backend codes' functions variable values?

Tags: javascript, server, backend

Say I have a function in my backend that takes inputs x and y, and returns `(x + y) * 3`.

When the user inputs x and y, say x = 3 and y = 5, and calls the function, can the people that host my server see the value 8 (resulting from x + y)?

Comment: A bit of clarification, but 1) Do you host your backend (servers)? 2) Is this function plugged into HTTP processing (so users can actually interact with it)?

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept! Is there anything I can add to also make the answer upvote worthy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the answer is: it is possible. Maybe not likely, but possible.

You see, the people that *host* a service have (most likely) access to the hardware, and the operating system running it. Any reasonable hosting service will put in security means. They should make it *impossible* for other users of the hosting service to look *into* your service, and *almost impossible* for administrators of your hosting service to spy on their clients.